# How to add CloudMade map to ArcGIS Android?

Tags: eclipse, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I want to add a CloudMade map to Esri's Android [HelloWorld](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/hello-world.htm) application. I'm following the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/osm/OpenStreetMapLayer.html#OpenStreetMapLayer%28%29), but when I run the app, LogCat throws an EsriService Exception and the app closes. Below is the relevant code. Does anyone have an idea on what I need to change to display a CloudMade basemap? I posted this question on [ArcGIS Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/105624-Adding-OpenStreetMap-to-HelloWorld-in-10.2.2?p=376789#post376789) a few days ago, but no response there yet. I'm working with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 10.2.2. Thanks, Patty

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
MapView mMapView;

 // Called when the activity is first created.
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
 String[] tileServerURL = {"http://b.tile.cloudmade.com/{KEY}/1/256"};
 OpenStreetMapLayer tileLayer = new OpenStreetMapLayer(tileServerURL, 1, 16, "CloudMade", true);
 tileLayer.setKey("myKey"); 

 mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer); //when this line is commented out the app runs, but only with an Esri base map
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the app runs when you comment out the `mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer)` is that the `MapView`'s basemap is set in XML.  Open up the `/res/layout/main.xml` file and comment out all the `mapoptions` parameters.  Your XML should look like this:

`<!-- MapView layout, including basemap layer, initial center point, and zoom level -->
  <com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />`

I can confirm that the url you provide resolves to `http://b.tile.cloudmade.com/myKey/1/256` at runtime.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I added the code you gave to my XML. The app remain opens now when I run it, but I see the Open Street Map, not the map I am specifying via CloudMade. I tried other URLs from this   [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers) too. If you have other suggestions, please let me know. Thanks, patty

Comment: I am confused when you put in your CloudMade URL setting the key in the API you get the Open Street Map and not your map?

Comment: Yeah, I think what's happening is that the OSM I set as the base layer in the arcgis.com map called in this Android app is displaying. This would indicate I'm still a little stuck on how to call a cloudmade map in this application. Tomorrow I'm going to create a map service containing my vector data. That should at least put me in better shape for testing a new base map. Thanks,